# MySQL insert multiple rows in place of one

Tags: mysql-python

How can we insert multiple row by replacing one row in Mysql.

Example:

```
Group_Id   Name  
 1         John  
 1         Snow  
 1         Hank
```

Now snow died and in place of him, his two sons(Harry and Peter) come as given:

```
Group_Id   Name  
 1         John  
 1         Harry  
 1         Peter
 1         Hank
```

Comment: I solved this by using a position column which tells the position of every entry in the column inside a particular group id.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, either you update the Snow row (with one of the new ones) or you delete it and insert the two new lines.

```
Update table1 set Name = 'Peter' where Name like 'Snow'

Insert into table1 (Group_Id, Name) Values (1, 'Harry')
```

Additionally I would highly recommend to add an ID column and if you are new to databases to check some baseline documentation and best practices.

Comment: it will insert Harry after Hank but I want Harry before Hank.

Comment: a table itself is not ordered, you could add an 'Order' column. If you don't order by anything in your select, the order you actually get is more or less 'random'